# Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I have been on this problem for a while, I'm developing a ***Java Web App*** on local machine, with ***MySQL*** and using ***EclipseLink (JPA 2.1)***.

Everything was working just fine and even i was ***accessing my application***, but I realize that the table **'usuario'** need other columns on it so in that table 'usuario' I 'Alter' and insert five new columns.

How I insert those new columns on the table I re-generate the **Entity Class**, but for some reason when I try to login now throws me an error and can't access my application:

**This is the DB Table:**[image]

**Entity Class:** (the new columns than I insert are: **nombreCompleto, email, direccion, ciudad, estado**)

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Ramiro
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByPkUsuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.pkUsuario = :pkUsuario")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByUsuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.usuario = :usuario")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByContrasenia", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.contrasenia = :contrasenia")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByFechaCreacion", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.fechaCreacion = :fechaCreacion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByFechaUltimaEdicion", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.fechaUltimaEdicion = :fechaUltimaEdicion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByTipoUsuario", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.tipoUsuario = :tipoUsuario")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEstatus", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.estatus = :estatus")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByNombreCompleto", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.nombreCompleto = :nombreCompleto")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByDireccion", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.direccion = :direccion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByCiudad", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.ciudad = :ciudad")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Usuario.findByEstado", query = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u WHERE u.estado = :estado")})
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pkUsuario")
    private Integer pkUsuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "usuario")
    private String usuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "contrasenia")
    private String contrasenia;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fechaCreacion")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaCreacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "fechaUltimaEdicion")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date fechaUltimaEdicion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "tipoUsuario")
    private int tipoUsuario;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "estatus")
    private int estatus;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nombreCompleto")
    private String nombreCompleto;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "direccion")
    private String direccion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ciudad")
    private String ciudad;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "estado")
    private String estado;

    public Usuario() {
    }

    public Usuario(Integer pkUsuario) {
        this.pkUsuario = pkUsuario;
    }

    public Usuario(Integer pkUsuario, String usuario, String contrasenia, Date fechaCreacion, Date fechaUltimaEdicion, int tipoUsuario, int estatus, String nombreCompleto, String email, String direccion, String ciudad, String estado) {
        this.pkUsuario = pkUsuario;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
        this.fechaUltimaEdicion = fechaUltimaEdicion;
        this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
        this.estatus = estatus;
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
        this.email = email;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public Integer getPkUsuario() {
        return pkUsuario;
    }

    public void setPkUsuario(Integer pkUsuario) {
        this.pkUsuario = pkUsuario;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getContrasenia() {
        return contrasenia;
    }

    public void setContrasenia(String contrasenia) {
        this.contrasenia = contrasenia;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getFechaUltimaEdicion() {
        return fechaUltimaEdicion;
    }

    public void setFechaUltimaEdicion(Date fechaUltimaEdicion) {
        this.fechaUltimaEdicion = fechaUltimaEdicion;
    }

    public int getTipoUsuario() {
        return tipoUsuario;
    }

    public void setTipoUsuario(int tipoUsuario) {
        this.tipoUsuario = tipoUsuario;
    }

    public int getEstatus() {
        return estatus;
    }

    public void setEstatus(int estatus) {
        this.estatus = estatus;
    }

    public String getNombreCompleto() {
        return nombreCompleto;
    }

    public void setNombreCompleto(String nombreCompleto) {
        this.nombreCompleto = nombreCompleto;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (pkUsuario != null ? pkUsuario.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Usuario)) {
            return false;
        }
        Usuario other = (Usuario) object;
        if ((this.pkUsuario == null && other.pkUsuario != null) || (this.pkUsuario != null && !this.pkUsuario.equals(other.pkUsuario))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "hg.entity.Usuario[ pkUsuario=" + pkUsuario + " ]";
    }

    }
```

***Note:*** If I delete the five new parameters just here on the Entity the error does not appears any more (but I need those parameters).

**//Search if the user exist (Here is where the error is thrown)**

```
private List<Usuario> findUsrByUsrPass(String usr, EntityManager em){        
    List<Usuario> results = em.createNamedQuery("Usuario.findByUser").setParameter("usuario", usr).getResultList();
    return results;   
}
```

**The error:**

```
    [EL Info]: 2017-05-04 18:26:04.041--ServerSession(1801367825)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2017-05-04 18:26:04.598--ServerSession(1801367825)--file:/C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache Tomcat 8.0.27/temp/15-Hagen/WEB-INF/lib/HagenBack.jar_HagenBackPU login successful
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'ciudad' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT pkUsuario, ciudad, contrasenia, direccion, email, estado, estatus, fechaCreacion, fechaUltimaEdicion, nombreCompleto, tipoUsuario, usuario FROM usuario WHERE (usuario = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Usuario.findByUsuario" referenceClass=Usuario sql="SELECT pkUsuario, ciudad, contrasenia, direccion, email, estado, estatus, fechaCreacion, fechaUltimaEdicion, nombreCompleto, tipoUsuario, usuario FROM usuario WHERE (usuario = ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
```

I can left those columns on the DB, and if I remove those five new columns of the Entity I can access my application again.

*¿What I'm losing? 
¿It's there something wrong on my Entity or it is a bug from EclipseLink?*

I already try to delete and re-generate the table 'usuario', Cleaning and Building the app, etc; etc; but it looks like MySQL don't refresh the table on the memory or something like that.

I appreciate any help. Regards.

Comment: suppose you drop the table `usuario` in the database and re create it using application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found it's to delete all tables on the DB and reinserting after that just recreate all the entities (Entity Classes from Database). I know this is a bad solution in future use if the tables has thousands of values, but for the moment, it works. Regards.